# Show number of sessions from organic keywords by language

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

So i need to see how much sessions is made by certain organic keyword, also by each language. The problem is that there is many variations of language codes, for example: en and en-us so all my keywords are split.

```
There is certan number of sessions for keyword A for en
And there is also certain number of session for keyford A for en-us
```

Example of keyword sessions being split couse of language code: http://prntscr.com/483p1i

How do i show traffic from both variation of language code so it is not split in 2?

The same problem is also for other languages. How can i get the report that i need? I tried in Acquisition > Keywords > Organic and also Audience > Geo > Language, but i always get stuck with multiple language codes for same languages.

Answer (score 0):

Set language as second dimension, choose advancend filter, select language as dimension to filter by and select "contains" as condition (you could also use regular expressions, but this is the simple option). Then "en" will give you en-us, en-gb and other combinations.

[image]

The first line in the resulting data table will give you the totals for the chosen language.

Comment: i dont need the totals, that is the problem, i need a report for all keywords for all language codes en and en-us and oothers, just not shown separatly: keywordA 125 sessions language:en, keaywordA 89 sessions language:en-us

Comment: Well, the data table below will give you the numbers for every language code with (in this example) "en".

Comment: i added a image to my post explaining better what i need. take a look atthe problem here with keyword traffic being split in 2: http://prntscr.com/483p1i